# Dynamically create submenu

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a TMainMenu with a menu item called mnuWindows. I wish to create submenu items dynamically. I thought this code might do it but it doesn't work:

```
var
  mnuitm: TMenuItem;

mnuitm:=TMenuItem.Create(nil);
mnuitm.Text:='some text';
mnuWindows.AddObject(mnuitm);
```

When I click on mnuWIndows, nothing happens. Where am i going wrong?

**EDIT:**

The submenu was not displaying on clicking because each time I did so, the program had been freshly started and I didn't realize that under these circumstances, two clicks are necessary. The first click doesn't visibly do anything and the second click drops down the submenu. So, I concede the code snippet above works.

But I still have a difficulty. I need to create several submenu items so I tried the following loop inside the mnuWindows OnClick event handler:

```
for I := 0 to TabSet1.Tabs.Count - 1 do
begin
  mnuitm := TMenuItem.Create(mnuWindows);
  mnuitm.Text := TabSet1.Tabs[I].Text;
  mnuitm.OnClick:=MenuItemClick;
  if not mnuWindows.ContainsObject(mnuitm) then
    mnuWindows.AddObject(mnuitm);
end;
```

The intent of the above code is that clicking the mnuWindows item displays a list of the tabs in a tabset. This code works up to a point. On first being clicked, it correctly lists the current tabs. But when I add a tab and click on mnuWindows again, the new tab is not shown in the list. The list is exactly as before. I wondered if the menu needed updating or refreshing somehow. I came across the following method

```
IFMXMenuService.UpdateMenuItem(IItemsContainer, TMenuItemChanges)
```

but it is poorly documented and I'm not sure how to use it or even whether it is relevant.

**EDIT2:**
I thought the two down votes on my post were harsh. I have searched the web extensively for an example of how to dynamically create submenus in Firemonkey and there is very little. I did find [a solution from 2012](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/0/permalink.art-ng2027q6103), but syntax changes since then mean that it does not work in Tokyo 10.2.

Comment: What you have shown is exactly what the [`TMenuItem` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Menus.TMenuItem) says to do: "*You can add submenu items to the current TMenuItem by using the AddObject procedure of the TMenuItem.*" If it is not working, [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: I use the exact same code in my App and it works for me. Only difference is that I pass my TMainMenu as the owner to TMenuItem.Create().

Comment: What are you expecting mnuitm to do? You don't have an OnClick handler assigned to it.

Comment: You've not given it an event handler for OnClick. Do you expect it to magically understand what you expect when it's clicked via mind reading? Delphi is good, but it has not progressed to the level of reading your thoughts yet; you still have to write the code to get it to do things.

Comment: @Duns Yes it works with 10.2 Tokyo. I do assign OnClick event though, so that's another difference.

Comment: To all who commented on the lack of an OnClick handler, I deliberately left it out of my code snippet because that was not an aspect causing me difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question.

As a reminder, what I wanted to do was to dynamically create a submenu under my top level menu item "Windows" (component name "mnuWindows"). In the submenu, I wished to list the names of the tabs in a tabset.

Attempting to create the submenu dynamically in the mnuWindows.OnClick event was a failure.

My eventual solution was to rebuild the submenu with the following method and to call this method immediately after creating a new tab, removing a tab, or renaming a tab:

```
procedure Form1.ReBuildWindowsMenu;
var
  mnuitm: TMenuItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
  mnuWindows.Clear; // removes submenu items
  for I := 0 to TabSet1.Tabs.Count - 1 do
  begin
    mnuitm := TMenuItem.Create(MainMenu1);
    mnuitm.Caption:= TabSet1.Tabs[I].Text; // submenu item displays same text as associated tab
    mnuitm.OnClick := MenuItemClick; // makes the associated tab active
    mnuWindows.AddObject(mnuitm);
  end;
end;
```

The OnClick handler contains the single statement

```
TabSet1.ActiveTabIndex:=(Sender as TMenuItem).Index;
```

This simple solution keeps my Windows list perfectly synched with the tabs in the tabset. I'm planning to use a similar approach to put a most recently used (MRU) file list into my File menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. As others have commented above, you need to provide an event that will happen when the menu item is clicked. Note also that my methods here require a bunch of parameters. It would have been cleaner if I had created a class and passed the details that way, but I wrote this a long time ago and now have many places in my code that use it in this form. Also, if I wrote this now, I would use a function to return the menu item created in case I needed to interact with it in particular cases (e.g., check it, assign a hot key, etc.)

```
procedure PopMenuAddItem(menu: TPopupMenu; sText: string; iID: integer;
  clickEvent: TNotifyEvent; bEnabled: boolean = true);
var
  NewMenuItem: TmenuItem;
begin
  NewMenuItem := TmenuItem.create(menu);
  with NewMenuItem do
  begin
    Caption := sText;
    tag := iID;
    Enabled := bEnabled;
    OnClick := clickEvent;
 end;
 menu.Items.Add(NewMenuItem);
end;

procedure PopMenuAddSubItem(menuItem: TmenuItem; sText: string; iID: integer;
  clickEvent: TNotifyEvent; bEnabled: boolean = true);
var
  NewMenuItem: TmenuItem;
begin
  NewMenuItem := TmenuItem.create(menuItem);
  with NewMenuItem do begin
    Caption := sText;
    tag := iID;
    Enabled := bEnabled;
    OnClick := clickEvent;
  end;
  menuItem.Add(NewMenuItem);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks but that is VCL code not FMX. For example, there is no Add method, it's now AddObject.